# Write file to This PC

Tags: vb.net, file, windows-10

I'm developing a VB.NET application (on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2010) where I'd like to create a file on an USB plugged Android device.
The folder where I'd like to write the file is `This PC\Archos\Internal storage\Download\`.

In VB.NET, I try to create my file with the instruction above:

```
File.WriteAllText("This PC\Archos\Internal storage\Download\", myTextFile)
```

If I do that, my app doesn't recognize the This PC path as a real path and the path is concatenated with the application path so something like:

```
C:\APP\NET\DEBUG\This PC\Archos\....
```

If I try to do the `File.WriteAllText("C:\MyRandomPath", text)` it'll work but I can't access my device storage with C.

So, is it possible to write a text in a folder in `This PC`? Is it a secret full path to access to `This PC`?

I found nothing but the possibility to open a file dialog on This PC but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Try removing `This PC` altogether and just start with a leading ``\``.

Comment: If I do that it'll add `C:` and will try to write the file to `C:\Archos\...` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Sorry, try ``\\Archos\...``.

Comment: I got the following error: `The network path was not found`.

Comment: That FileSystem is not mounted as a local device. See: [Windows Portable Devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windows-portable-devices) and [WPD Programming Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wpd_sdk/programming-reference)

Comment: Open the file properties of any file in your target location from Windows explorer and check what the reported path is.

Comment: BTW, you can do the same operations using the Shell object. If you don't dislike `C#`, I can make a couple of examples, to copy files to/from an Android device (unmounted).

Comment: @Jimi I don't really see how to use it but I'll seek examples. 
@NicoSchertler The path in properties is `This PC\Archos\Internal Storage\...`.
@Jimi The file transfer I'm developing is part of a very large VB.net application. I suppose I can't code this part in C# and integrate it to the VB app, can I?

Comment: PInvoking works the same in both C# and VB.Net. But, you can use the Windows Shell to do the same thing. I left some comments in a similar question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59340979/7444103) (you seem to share the same interest at the same time with similar *wording*...). Using the Shell interfaces, you can easily enumerate Android devices, copy/move files to/from a device with simple commands. The drawback: when you add a reference to `shell32.dll`,  platform-specific Interfaces GUIDs are generated. You have to compile on the same platform (Windows) version that will use the code.

Comment: @Jimi Thanks I'll try to use the windows shell then thanks to your comments (this post is just a coincidence, I'm not a native speaker if it explains the simple wording). This solution looks like the best solution even if I'm not sure to have the level to develop it. If I can't I'll probably use MTPdrive to have a drive for the device.

Comment: With *(...) similar wording* I meant the use of more or less the same *terms* (`This PC`, *open a file dialog*, etc.). I though you were, possibly, colleagues, so my comment might have been a *deja vu*. Using the Shell interfaces is quite simple, actually, no *special skills* required. When you add a reference to `Shell32.dll`, Visual Studio will add a Project reference to `Microsoft Shell Controls And Automation` (but you'll see `Shell32` under `References` in Solution Explorer). Give it a shot. You can find lots of code samples around. Write back if you hit a snag.